# how to parse places XML api and mark on google maps

Tags: java, android, xml, api, android-studio

I am working on a android studio project that tells nearby places using XML api but it is a non google service.

I want to parse all XML data and that contain coordinates of places, I need to know how to parse that and display on google maps.

My Xml response

```
<ArrayOfmasjid xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DBase.DataObjectModel">
<masjid>
<Distance i:nil="true"/>
<_id xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MongoDB.Bson">
<d3p1:_a>1471915691</d3p1:_a>
<d3p1:_b>1140779876</d3p1:_b>
<d3p1:_c>-398269374</d3p1:_c>
</_id>
<masjidAddress>
<city>Bhopal</city>
<country>India</country>
<description i:nil="true"/>
<googlePlaceId>ChIJTRpmAyJofDkRoddd-ANr4XM</googlePlaceId>
<locality>Peer Gate Area</locality>
<phone i:nil="true"/>
<state>Madhya Pradesh</state>
<street>Chowk Bazaar Rd</street>
<zipcode>462001</zipcode>
</masjidAddress>
<masjidCreatedby>saud@saudkhan.net</masjidCreatedby>
<masjidCreatedon>2016-08-23T01:28:10.789Z</masjidCreatedon>
<masjidId>57bba6ab43feeb64e842e442</masjidId>
<masjidLocation>
<coordinates xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<d4p1:double>77.4019681</d4p1:double>
<d4p1:double>23.2586956</d4p1:double>
</coordinates>
<type>Point</type>
</masjidLocation>
<masjidModifiedby>saud@saudkhan.net</masjidModifiedby>
<masjidModifiedon>2016-08-23T01:28:10.789Z</masjidModifiedon>
<masjidName>Jama Masjid</masjidName>
<masjidPic i:nil="true"/>
<masjidTimings>
<asr i:nil="true"/>
<fajr i:nil="true"/>
<isha i:nil="true"/>
<jumah i:nil="true"/>
<maghrib i:nil="true"/>
<zuhr i:nil="true"/>
</masjidTimings>
<notMasjid>false</notMasjid>
</masjid>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Make a function that you can call like `String value = getStringBetween(xmlText, "<country>, "</country");` Not much work.

Comment: I am totally new at this can you please elaborate how?

Comment: Use functions String.indexOf() and String.substring().